# Couldn't find package "babel-present-react" on the "npm" registry

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs

```
yarn add babel-loader babel-core babel-present-es2015 babel-present-react --dev
```

This command is giving me an error that "Couldn't find package "babel-present-react" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command."

Comment: I think you meant `babel-preset-react` (no `n`).

Comment: yes, it was a typing mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you are looking for is `babel-preset-react`
So replace `present` with `preset` and you'll be good.